# Specified cast is not valid in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have

1. CustomerViewModel

   ```
    public class CustomerViewModel: BaseCustomerViewModel
    {
     ICustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerService();
     public Command LoadCustomerCommand { get; }
     public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; }
     public CustomerViewModel()
     {
        LoadCustomerCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadCustomerCommand());
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
     }
    }
    ...
   ```
2. Customer (Models)

   ```
    public class Customer
    {
      public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
      public string NameUs { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. ViewProductViewModel

   ```
    public class ViewProductViewModel:BaseProductViewModel
    {
      public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; }
      public ViewProductViewModel()
      {
        ProductInfo = new ProductInfo();
      }        
    }
   ```
4. Page1.xml.cs

   ```
   public Customer _customer { get; set; }
   public DetailProduct(ProductInfo productInfo)
   {     
      BindingContext = new ViewProductViewModel();
      string idstore = productInfo.StoreID;  
      _customer = ((ViewProductViewModel)BindingContext).Customers.Where(user => user.PhoneNum == idstore).FirstOrDefault();
      productInfo.NameStoreID = _customer.NameUs;
   }
   ```

I want to get the **NameUs** from the **Customer (Models)** class. This is how I want to get NameUs information from CustomerViewModel with condition `PhoneNum == idstore`.

However, I get the error **Specified cast is not valid** when debugging immediately the line `_customer = ((ViewProductViewModel)BindingContext).Customers.Where(user => user.PhoneNum == idstore).FirstOrDefault();`

Any solution I would like to thank!

**Update**

After I update `BindingContext = new ViewProductViewModel()`; error: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'

Initializing and loading any data into Customers in VM constructor.

```
public class CustomerViewModel: BaseCustomerViewModel
{
    ICustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerService();
    public Command LoadCustomerCommand { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; }
    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        LoadCustomerCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadCustomerCommand());
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadCustomerCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Customers.Clear();
            var customerList = await customerRepository.GetCustomersAsync();
            foreach (var customer in customerList)
            {
                Customers.Add(customer);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you assigning `BindingContext`?

Comment: Sorry, I updated it more clearly

Comment: You did not answer my question.  You are trying to cast `BindingContext`, but nowhere in your code are you actually assigning it a value.

Comment: ya, I updated BindingContext = new ViewProductViewModel(); you can see, i'm a bit confused :(

Comment: did that fix your error?

Comment: When I debug, I get an error: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'

Comment: You are not initializing or loading any data into `Customers` in your VM constructor.  You are just creating a command but not executing it.

Comment: I created a new VM to get the Customer above. So what should I do next? Could you please describe it in detail for me?

Comment: I tried adding: Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(); inside public ViewProductViewModel()

Comment: that creates an empty list, but it doesn't load the data

Comment: How can I get the Customer list from the CustomerViewModel I updated above

Comment: you need to call the method that loads the data - ExecuteLoadCustomerCommand

Comment: I created: public class CustomerViewModel: BaseCustomerViewModel the above update. Is there any way I can call it back and use it? And how to reuse? Or is it mandatory to "you need to call the method that loads the data - ExecuteLoadCustomerCommand"--> as your opinion?

Comment: `LoadCustomerCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadCustomerCommand());` just **creates** the command, it does not actually **execute** it.  Until you execute it, or call that method some other way, you will not have any data.

Comment: Can you guide the code more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewProductViewModel, the Customers property is just defined and not instantiated. So when you use "Customers." there will be a null value error. You need to instantiate the Customers in the ViewProductViewModel.

Comment: I will try to try and will report back to you. Tks

Comment: I have made a new question more clear, hope you can help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920650/how-to-get-data-outside-binding-in-xamarin